# Setting Up a Network For Development in Hyperledger Fabric v0.5-preview

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

My demo project is running OK already, but it is only one peer in network. I want to add more peers into network.
I followed this guide ==> [https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/blob/540c4db5f64dba4bd1b18e896c96a8d17d7ec552/docs/dev-setup/devnet-setup.md](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/dev-setup/devnet-setup.md).

Please kindly help to check the log below, 
the directory was wrong? or what is the right way to run this start up of peer?

```
vagrant@hyperledger-devenv:v-:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric$ docker run --rm -it -e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375 -e CORE_PEER_ID=vp0 -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true hyperledger-peer peer node start
Unable to find image 'hyperledger-peer:latest' locally
Pulling repository docker.io/library/hyperledger-peer
docker: Error: image library/hyperledger-peer not found.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: can you add what do you get when you run `docker images`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that first node in network was started not in Docker container? (For example it could be started as a process using `peer node start`)

We can verify which docker images are available in vagrant machine. Just run `docker images` command:

```
vagrant@hyperledger-devenv:v0.0.9-b4acc4b:$ docker images
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
hyperledger/fabric-baseimage   latest              c1d6f4800a55        27 hours ago        1.297 GB
hyperledger/fabric-baseimage   x86_64-0.0.9        70328eed56aa        2 weeks ago         990.1 MB
busybox                        latest              47bcc53f74dc        9 weeks ago         1.113 MB
```

With such configuration, when “hyperledger-peer” image is not available, the Validation Peer will not be started because of “Unable to find image” error:

```
vagrant@hyperledger-devenv:v0.0.9-b4acc4b:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer$ docker run --rm -it -e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375 -e CORE_PEER_ID=vp0 -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true hyperledger-peer peer node start
Unable to find image 'hyperledger-peer:latest' locally
Pulling repository docker.io/library/hyperledger-peer
docker: Error: image library/hyperledger-peer not found.
```

"hyperledger-peer:latest" image can be created using:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/container
go test -run BuildImage_Peer
```

Now `docker images` should show one more available image:

```
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
hyperledger-peer               latest              438b65f18f21        8 seconds ago       1.418 GB
```

at this point Validation Peer should be started successfully:

```
vagrant@hyperledger-devenv:v0.0.9-b4acc4b:~$ docker run —rm -it -e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375 -e CORE_PEER_ID=vp0 -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true hyperledger-peer peer node start
21:55:51.969 [crypto] main -> INFO 001 Log level recognized 'info', set to INFO
21:55:51.970 [peer] func1 -> INFO 002 Auto detected peer address: 172.17.0.2:30303
21:55:51.971 [peer] func1 -> INFO 003 Auto detected peer address: 172.17.0.2:30303
21:55:51.972 [peer] func1 -> INFO 004 Auto detected peer address: 172.17.0.2:30303
21:55:51.974 [main] serve -> INFO 005 Security enabled status: false
21:55:51.974 [main] serve -> INFO 006 Privacy enabled status: false
…
```